# Changing color in angular todo list

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

hi this my first time here so be patience with me plz i stock in a problem
that i need to change a color in a span class this is my code

the color need to change in a click event when i click the checkbox from somecolor to grey

also if someone want to help i try to do select with selected option but in angular

tnx for the helper.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.priority = ['Urgent', 'Critical', 'Normal', 'IfYouCan']

  $scope.todos = [{
    text: 'Attend Selection Day',
    done: false,
    lvl: 'Critical'
  }, {
    text: 'Register to Full Stack Web Course',
    done: false,
    lvl: 'Normal'
  }, {
    text: 'Go see X-Man apocalypse movie',
    done: false,
    lvl: 'IfYouCan'
  }];

  $scope.addTodo = function() {

    $scope.todos.push({
      text: $scope.todoText,
      done: false,
      lvl: $scope.todoLvl
    });

    $scope.todoText = '';
  };

  $scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
      count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });


    return count;
  };

  $scope.archive = function() {
    var oldTodos = $scope.todos;

    $scope.todos = [];

    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
      if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
    });
  };
}
```

```css
.todo-true {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: grey;
}

.todo-Urgent {
  color: red;
}

.todo-Critical {
  color: orange;
}

.todo-Normal {
  color: green;
}

.todo-IfYouCan {
  color: RoyalBlue;
}

div.frame {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 50px;
}

div.todo {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div class="frame">
    <h2>Todo</h2>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">

      <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoText" size="30" placeholder="add new todo here">
        <select ng-init="todoLvl = priority[2]" ng-model="todoLvl">
          <option ng-repeat="item in priority" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
        </select>
        <button ng-click="addTodo()" type="button">add</button>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <span>{{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining</span>
      <br />
      <div ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
        <span class="done-{{todo.done}}"><span class="todo-{{todo.lvl}}">{{todo.text}} {{todo.lvl}}</span></span>
      </div>
      <br />
      <a href="" ng-click="archive()">Completed</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your question is just fine! Read about [ngClass](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass) then you can also utilze this directive instead of `todo-{{todo.lvl}}` ==> `ng-class="{'todo-Critical': todo.lvl == 'Critical','todo-Normal': todo.lvl == 'Normal'}"`. It gives you control for when you need to toggle between different classes based on rules you define in your application

Comment: Niv, if my answer helped you please mark it with "V", or let me know what still not working out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add "ng-class" for based on your todo.done (ng-model).

Also add more specific selector for color.

```js
function TodoCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.priority = ['Urgent', 'Critical', 'Normal', 'IfYouCan']

  $scope.todos = [{
    text: 'Attend Selection Day',
    done: false,
    lvl: 'Critical'
  }, {
    text: 'Register to Full Stack Web Course',
    done: false,
    lvl: 'Normal'
  }, {
    text: 'Go see X-Man apocalypse movie',
    done: false,
    lvl: 'IfYouCan'
  }];

  $scope.addTodo = function() {

    $scope.todos.push({
      text: $scope.todoText,
      done: false,
      lvl: $scope.todoLvl
    });

    $scope.todoText = '';
  };

  $scope.remaining = function() {
    var count = 0;

    angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
      count += todo.done ? 0 : 1;
    });


    return count;
  };

  $scope.archive = function() {
    var oldTodos = $scope.todos;

    $scope.todos = [];

    angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
      if (!todo.done) $scope.todos.push(todo);
    });
  };
}
```

```css
span.todo-true {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: grey;
}

.todo-Urgent {
  color: red;
}

.todo-Critical {
  color: orange;
}

.todo-Normal {
  color: green;
}

.todo-IfYouCan {
  color: RoyalBlue;
}

div.frame {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px 0px 0px 50px;
}

div.todo {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
  <div class="frame">
    <h2>Todo</h2>
    <div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">

      <div>
        <input type="text" ng-model="todoText" size="30" placeholder="add new todo here">
        <select ng-init="todoLvl = priority[2]" ng-model="todoLvl">
          <option ng-repeat="item in priority" value="{{item}}">{{item}}</option>
        </select>
        <button ng-click="addTodo()" type="button">add</button>
      </div>
      <hr />
      <span>{{remaining()}} of {{todos.length}} remaining</span>
      <br />
      <div ng-repeat="todo in todos">
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
        <span class="done-{{todo.done}}"><span class="todo-{{todo.lvl}}" ng-class="{'todo-true': todo.done}">{{todo.text}} {{todo.lvl}}</span></span>
      </div>
      <br />
      <a href="" ng-click="archive()">Completed</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tnx for your help (: